# Elasticsearch filter "should" results with geolocation params

Tags: elasticsearch

How to filter results from wildcard query with geolocation? My query look like this

```
{
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "should": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "title": {
                        "value": "*football*"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "description": {
                        "value": "*football*"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "90km",
                "geolocation" : "45.50, 40.10"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But query always return results by geo_distance, like to skip wildcard params. I want to return only results where distance is max 90km but which contains "football" in title or description...

Comment: I think, you should use `must` instead of `should`.

Comment: I am beginner with ES but I think 'must' not work with something like SQL '..where like ? or like ?...'  query. Val answer is what I looking for. However thanx for replay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add [`minimum_should_match: 1`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) in your query:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool" : {
        "minimum_should_match": 1,                       <-- add this
        "should": [
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "title": {
                        "value": "*football*"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "wildcard": {
                    "description": {
                        "value": "*football*"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "90km",
                "geolocation" : "45.50, 40.10"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you very much